# Why is the copy constructor of this template class not getting called?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, copy, copy-constructor

The copy constructor never gets called (I'm using g++ with -std=c++11):
pointers.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class SharedPtr
{
private:
    int *m_Count;
    T *m_Ptr;

public:
    SharedPtr(T *ptr = nullptr)
        : m_Count(new int), m_Ptr(ptr)
    {
        *m_Count = 1;
    }

    SharedPtr(const SharedPtr &other)
        : m_Count(other.m_Count), m_Ptr(other.m_Ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Copied: " << *m_Count << std::endl;
        (*m_Count)++;
    }

    ~SharedPtr()
    {
        (*m_Count)--;
        if (*m_Count == 0)
        {
            delete m_Ptr;
            delete m_Count;
        }
    }

    T &operator*()
    {
        return *m_Ptr;
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pointers.cpp"
#include <iostream>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity created!" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    {
        SharedPtr<Entity> e0;
        std::cin.get();
        {
            SharedPtr<Entity> sharedEntity = new Entity();
            std::cin.get();
            e0 = sharedEntity;
            std::cin.get();
        }
        std::cin.get();
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I looked at other similar questions asked here, but none of them worked.
The copy constructor should be `ClassName(const ClassName &other)`, right?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam lacinia mattis arcu, vitae interdum leo. Praesent viverra, tortor a tincidunt ullamcorper, arcu urna finibus enim, congue dignissim tortor quam ut dui. Ut eleifend suscipit ligula sagittis consequat. Integer semper orci eu metus mollis sodales. Fusce sollicitudin elementum nisl, non congue odio lobortis non. Duis tempus tristique nisi nec tempor. Sed in ullamcorper nisi. Suspendisse id suscipit magna, eu pellentesque ligula. Nullam aliquam pretium tellus, eget venenatis eros pharetra finibus.

Comment: `e0 = sharedEntity;` calls copy assignment operator, not copy constructor. No new instance is being constructed on this line.

Comment: Don't know how I did't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the code in `main()` calls the copy contructor of `SharedPtr`:

- `SharedPtr<Entity> e0;` calls `SharedPtr(T *ptr = nullptr)`
- `SharedPtr<Entity> sharedEntity = new Entity();` calls `SharedPtr(T *ptr = nullptr)`
- `e0 = sharedEntity;` calls `operator=()` which is not defined in your `SharedPtr`